# Can't connect to twilsock while creating Client

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

i am using Twilio with react and when i create the client using this code

```
this.chatClient = new Chat(this.state.token);
```

but i keep geting this error

```
TransportUnavailableError: Can't connect to twilsock
at Upstream.send (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:96516:31)
at TwilsockClient.post (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:94626:28)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:88943:33
at Retrier.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:88882:11)
at Retrier.push../node_modules/events/events.js.EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:25082:17)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the issue that we're discussing over here? https://github.com/philnash/react-programmable-chat/issues/6

Comment: yes it is the same issue

Comment: Ok, I see you have sorted it with Twilio support. Good luck with the rest of your app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues were between my device and Twilio. so I run the test bellow to find out what was the issue for me it was a network/firewall issue. fixed that and now it is working

```
https://networktest.twilio.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone arrived at this post who wasn't having network/firewall issues.

I was getting this error periodically using Twilio Sync. It was caused by an invalid token or in my case when the token expired after a period of time. You need to handle refreshing the token, similar to this:

```
_syncClient = new SyncClient(getNewToken());

_syncClient.on('tokenAboutToExpire', function() {
       _syncClient.updateToken(getNewToken());
});
```